# Login and Register Using Linked List-Can't access object created from other servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have created two servlet page 1st-servlet page is RegistrationServlet and 2nd- servlet page is LoginServlet, and made an object for linked list so as to call it from other servlet but I am not able to call that object.

```
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    String name,email,pass;

    name=request.getParameter("un");
    email = request.getParameter("em");
    pass = request.getParameter("pass");

    LinkedList<String> a1=new LinkedList();  
    a1.add(name);
     a1.add(pass);

    if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !pass.isEmpty()) {
      RequestDispatcher rd=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Login.html");
        rd.forward(request, response);

        request.getSession().setAttribute("someone", a1);
     request.getRequestDispatcher("LoginServlet").forward(request, response);
    } else {
        RequestDispatcher rd1 = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Register.html");
        rd1.include(request, response);
    }   
    }

    Other Servlet---------------------------------------
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException  {
    processRequest(request, response);
    String email = request.getParameter("eml");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");


        object fg;
    fg = request.getSession().getAttribute("someone");


     if(email.equals(fg.a1.get(0)) && pass.equals(fg.a1.get(1)))
    {
     System.out.println("sucess");

     }
      else{
        System.out.println("not");

      }   
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You put list into session by this command: request.getSession().setAttribute("someone", a1);
'a1' is a name of variable and is not put into session.
Value given by request.getSession().getAttribute("someone") must by of type List. This object does not have field 'a1'. So to get item of that list you have to write fg.get(0), not fg.a1.get(0).